# Introduction chapter in LYX

Tags: lyx

Hey how can I add "Introduction" chapter (without number) in Lyx? I have only option "abstract". I would like this one chapter to be unnumbered and included in the table of contents

Comment: Select Chapter* or Section* or  in the  dropdown menu.

Comment: thanks it works, but how to add this to Table of Contents?

Comment: Then use normal chapters and go to Documents > Settings > Numbering & TOC

Comment: hmm first I use chapter* and I write "Introduction". But then it is invisible in TOC. I prefer chapter* because I dont want to have a number for Introduction. When I go to settings there is no chapter* to include in TOC

Comment: @JohhnWhite I think Fran's comment actually does what you want. Give it a try. To be clear, here are the steps: 1. use "Chapter". 2. then go to Document > Settings > Numbering & TOC and make sure "Numbered" is set to "No" for "Chapter". 3. press "OK". 4. compile to PDF. Does that work? If it works, I suggest you edit your question to specify you want it to show in the TOC, and I suggest that Fran writes an answer.

Comment: @scottkosty but when I change Numbered to "NO" then all chapters have no number, not just this introductory chapter. When I use chapter* I get an effect which I want but then this chapter is not included in TOC

Comment: @JohhnWhite I see, you just want it for one Chapter. I added an answer. Could you please edit your question to specify that you want it to show in the TOC?

Comment: @JohnWhite +1 thanks for the edits to the question. And welcome to tex.se! I look forward to your future LyX questions. Also note that we have a mailing list, lyx-users, which is a friendly list in case you're interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your cursor in the `Chapter*` layout, then go to Insert > TeX Code, and paste the following: `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foreword}`. The following screenshot is how it looks in LyX after doing this:

[image]